# Stored procedure calling and statement ignored

Tags: asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures

I am making a stored procedure for inserting record in a table and a file specifically which has more than 4000 characters i have set the data type to CLOB now i am getting the error on insert statement says statement ignored. Kindly tell me what's wrong with this procedure.also how to call it from ASP.NET project.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE Insrt (Tmplt_Id IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_Id% TYPE,
    Tmplt_Code IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_Code%TYPE,
    Tmplt_Title IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_Title%TYPE,
    CPY_ID IN RPT_TEMPLATE.CPY_ID%TYPE,
    DPT_ID IN RPT_TEMPLATE.DPT_ID% TYPE,
    SEC_ID IN RPT_TEMPLATE.SEC_ID% TYPE,
    LOC_ID IN RPT_TEMPLATE.LOC_ID% TYPE,
    RptGrp_Id IN RPT_TEMPLATE.RptGrp_Id%TYPE,
    Tmplt_FileAddress IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_FileAddress%TYPE,
    Entity_Id IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Entity_Id%TYPE,
    Tmplt_Active IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_Active%TYPE,
    Tmplt_Remarks IN  RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_Remarks%TYPE,
    Tmplt_EnteredBy  IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_EnteredBy%TYPE,
    Tmplt_EnteredWhen IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_EnteredWhen%TYPE,
    Tmplt_Document  IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_Document%TYPE,
    Tmplt_DocGeneration  IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_DocGeneration%TYPE,
    Tmplt_DocPrefix  IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_DocPrefix%TYPE,
    Tmplt_DocNoLength IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_DocNoLength%TYPE,
    Tmplt_AllowPadding IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_AllowPadding%TYPE,
    Module_Id IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Module_Id%TYPE,
    Tmplt_IsManualEntry IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_IsManualEntry%TYPE,
    Tmplt_ContainsGrid IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_ContainsGrid%TYPE,
    Tmplt_WarningLetter IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_WarningLetter%TYPE,
    Tmplt_AppriciationLetter IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_AppriciationLetter%TYPE,
    Tmplt_ExplanationLetter IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_ExplanationLetter%TYPE,
    Tmplt_GeneralCorrespondence IN RPT_TEMPLATE.Tmplt_GeneralCorrespondence%TYPE)
    is
    begin
    insert into RPT_TEMPLATE VALUES (Tmplt_Id ,
    Tmplt_Code ,
    Tmplt_Title ,
    CPY_ID ,
    DPT_ID ,
    SEC_ID,
    LOC_ID ,
    RptGrp_Id ,
    Tmplt_FileAddress ,
    Entity_Id ,
    Tmplt_Active ,
    Tmplt_Remarks ,
    Tmplt_EnteredBy ,
    Tmplt_EnteredWhen  ,
    Tmplt_Document ,
    Tmplt_DocGeneration ,
    Tmplt_DocPrefix ,
    Tmplt_DocNoLength ,
    Tmplt_AllowPadding ,
    Module_Id ,
    Tmplt_IsManualEntry ,
    Tmplt_ContainsGrid ,
    Tmplt_WarningLetter ,
    Tmplt_AppriciationLetter ,
    Tmplt_ExplanationLetter ,
    Tmplt_GeneralCorrespondence );
    end;
```

Comment: what is ORA error you are getting>

Comment: PL/SQL statement ignored from insert